# GDAL for C# does not contain all methods as in C++

Tags: gdal, c#

According to GDAL's official site, GDAL 2.1 OGRDataSource class is deprecated and GDALDataset should be used. Methods like OGR_DS_GetLayerByName should be replaced by GDALDatasetGetLayerByName().

Now in GDAL for C#, latest 2.1.0 version, I cannot find this new methods in the Gdal.Dataset class.

Where did they go?

Answer (score 3):

You've referenced the C++ API, but the functions you've listed are in the C API.

The C# API does mirror the C++ API, so instead of looking for the [GDALDatasetGetLayerByName](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_8h.html#a06e1dfa7103356cbb11929a36c2ec139) function, you need to be using the [GDALDataset::GetLayerByName](http://www.gdal.org/classGDALDataset.html#a576978fecfad68741b44719605cf637e) function on the GDALDataset class.

An example of this is given in the the GDAL C# bindings examples, such as [OGRLayerAlg](https://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/browser/trunk/gdal/swig/csharp/apps/OGRLayerAlg.cs#L76) (starting at line 76):

```csharp
DataSource ds1 = Ogr.Open(args[1], 0);
/* ... */
Layer layer1 = ds1.GetLayerByName(args[2]);
```

Comment: (damned Enter Key!)  I know there is not a direct name mapping. What I am trying to say is that in C++, in class Dataset, you have classes like GetLayerByName and GetLayerCount, but there is no call for this methods in C#. On the other hand Ogr.DataSource class is deprecated and we should start using Gdal.DataSet classes, so I am stuck! Thank you!

Comment: Putting things clearer. the method you are calling in the example (GetLayerByName) is deprecated for version 2.1.1. As an alternative the documentation states that one should use 'Gdal.Dataset.GetLayerByName'. Now in C# this methods are not implemented. This is my problem. Thank you